# Polymer: How to show paper-progress or spinner while rendering a template

Tags: polymer

Is there any way to show, for example paper-progress, only when data is rendered inside template and to hide it, when the rendering is complete ?

Answer (score 1):

Start paper progress at your element start and stop it when data rendered ie: on `<template is="dom-repeat">` data helper element.

```
<script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="../paper-styles/color.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-progress.html">
<style is="custom-style">
  paper-progress {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  paper-progress.blue {
    --paper-progress-active-color: var(--paper-light-blue-500);
    --paper-progress-secondary-color: var(--paper-light-blue-100);
  }

</style>
<paper-progress indeterminate class="blue" disabled="{{progresDisabled}}"></paper-progress>
<template is="dom-repeat" item='data' rendered-item-count="{{count}}">
     <div>[[data.name]]</div>
</template>
...
```

Observe the rendered item at dome repeat:

```
...
static get observers() { return ['checkToDisableProgress(count)'] }

 checkToDisableProgress(count){
        this.set('progresDisabled', count!=0 ? true : false)
 }
```